# Read permission for the entire intranet site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to give only read permission for a user to entire intranet site. The user must be able to read all the list and libraries in all the sites and subsites. I saw posts related to giving permission for a specific list or library but I didn't see any post related to giving read permission for the entire intranet site. I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Read access to everything in a single site collection, then that is hard to give generic advice to because assorted list, libraries and subwebs can have broken the permission inheritance such that it would be impossible for an outsider to tell you which groups this person needs to be a member of.

Now if you mean you want a user to have Read access to all site collections within a web application, then that is absolutely something that can be accomplished and it is very easy too.  That is done via something called: Policy for Web Applications - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071.aspx